# Kafka streams : how to handle dynamic conditions in a filter?

Tags: java, filter, apache-kafka, stream

Is there any way to handle a dynamic condition in a kafka stream ?
I need to filter my streamed data by a list of values changed by users, but this list of values are not in a stream, they are available by an http call.

```
stream(myTopic)
    .filter(isDataOK())
    ...

private Predicate<> isDataOK() {
     http_call;
     return predicate_value_based_on_http_answer;
}
```

Is it possible to handle http call during kafka stream processing or do I need  the conditional data in an other stream ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: It is possible, but it is not proper approach. http call can be _heavy_, throw an exception, etc and it can slow down processing or even stop it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirements for the dynamic stream configuration. Calling http for every message processing is not a good idea as it is time consuming. It is better to cache values in your processing component and update them on some regular basis, for example, once per hour. You should also think about the scenario when the http call is not available.

In another project I was receiving the dynamic configuration asynchronously from another Kafka topic and this worked better and more natural for stream processing.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer, I share your opinion and I will create a schedule function as a quickly solution and create another kafka topic with my setup for a longtime solution.
But in fact, I'm also interested by a technical solution without schedule or provided topic just to understand how is it possible to do it.